# Inplace join sub arrays of 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array as this

```
a = array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6] .....])
```

I have two indexes as a tuple like this `(0,2)`. So I want to join the sub-arrays of these sub indexes in place. So the final expected output is somewhat like this-

```
a = array([[1,2,5,6], [3,4] .....])
```

After this join, there is no meaning of indexes and the order. That is, `[1,2,5,6]` may well come after `[3,4]`. Also, the sub-array size of 2 is just representative, it can also be non-uniform.
How to do this using some inbuilt numpy function(s)?

Comment: Numpy have fixed dimensions along all axes, so your desired result isn't even a valid Numpy array.  You can use a list of lists instead, though.

Comment: If you intent to get a ragged array like `[[1,2,5,6], [3,4]]` (4 elements in row 1 and 2 in row 2) you're out of luck because NumPy arrays need to be "rectangular". Except if you use object-arrays and don't care about speed. But then you could also just use plain Python lists.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think it'd be a good idea to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @MSeifert Technically, it's possible to use `dtype=object` to get that kind of array, but using that over a standard Python list only makes sense in rare circumstances.

Comment: Yes, but that's not really in-place because the final length would be original length - 1 so it would require getting a view or copy of the original array, but I also thought about objects-arrays and have edited the comment already :)

Comment: Okay, forget about numpy, how to do in simply python lists. Anyways, I already had a numpy array of dtype=object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `numpy` as `numpy arrays` require the same length `arrays` on **all** `axis`, however you can use nested `lists`.

So using `lists`, you can simply create a `function` to do what you want, so:

```
def joinSubs(lst, tpl):
    lst[tpl[0]] += lst[tpl[1]]
    lst.pop(tpl[1])
    return lst
```

then running:

```
joinSubs([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]], (0,2))
```

gives the `list` that you want **:)**:

```
[[1, 2, 5, 6], [3, 4]]
```

---

Note that if this `numpy array` is already heavily embedded in some of your other code and uses `numpy` `functions`, you can use [`.tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) to convert it to a `list`:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
>>> a.tolist()
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you want to stick with numpy.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
b = (0, 2)
a_final = np.array([np.delete(a, b, 0), a[[*b]].flatten()])
```